# Two-column SQL count query with first column having static labels

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g and I have a table called downloads which basically looks like this:

```
ID     DOWNLOAD_DATE
1      2011-02-10
2      2011-03-10
3      2011-04-10
4      2011-05-10
5      2011-01-11
6      2011-04-22
7      2011-02-18
8      2011-03-14
9      2011-02-01
10     2011-01-31
```

etc.

I would like to execute a query that returns the following:

```
Downloads today
Downloads yesterday
Downloads from start date until today
Downloads on start date
Downloads on day after start date
```

I would like to print the results in two columns. In the first column I'd like to put a static label, like the ones above. And in the second column the count.

I've tried something like this:

```
select count(id) from downloads where download_date = '2007-08-06'
union
select count(id) from downloads where download_date = '2007-08-08'
```

But this has 2 problems. One, it only prints one column, the count. Two, if there is no data for a given date (or range of dates), nothing is printed. I need a zero to be printed.

So then I tried something like this:

```
select download_date, count(download_date) from downloads where download_date = '2007-08-06'
group by download_date
union
select download_date, count(download_date) from downloads where download_date > '2007-08-08'
group by download_date
```

This returns two columns but the first column isn't static, it's a field in the database (download_date). And more importantly, it returns multiple rows for query that selects a range of dates (where download_date > '2007-08-08'), whereas I just want one row, with its count.

How can I do this?

Many thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 3):

First of all. Use `Union All` for this. Union will strip double records, which is probably not what you want in this case. It won't matter much, but union all is faster too. ;)

Second, I don't understand why you can't just put in a static label, like this:

```
select 'Look, static' from dual
```

Then, you could write a query like this:

```
select 
  'Downloads today' as Caption, 
  count(*) as DownloadCount 
from 
  Downloads where trunc(download_date) = trunc(sysdate)
union all
select 
  'Downloads yesterday'
  count(*)
from 
  Downloads where trunc(download_date) = trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

Count *will* print 0 if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a static label into each of your selects in the union version like this:

```
SELECT 'some label', ...
 UNION
 ...
```